# Installation vs Gem - Paperclip and ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am trying to install Paperclip on my Rails Project but it seems I need ImageMagick installed too too. 
I thought first ImageMagick was a gem to install but it is actually a piece of software.

My question is : 
Why not a gem ? 
And as it is a piece of software, will I get into trouble finding an hosting service that has ImageMagick installed too on their servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick is a command line utility for modifying images.  Paperclip uses it for resizing/thumbnailing image uploads.  If your hosting service gives you SSH access, you should be able to install it on your server(s).

Answer (score 1):

Propably NO.
I use Digitalocean for my projects and you can install imagemagick simple via their ssh. I suppose this happens to any vps service.